# I want to split routes of a main react application into multiple packages. How to do so?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react application that for example is abc.com.
I want to have a separate package that is called when someone routes to abc.com/serviceA
and serviceA package will have multiple routes in itself, that gets appended to abc.com/serviceA/id=123 etc...

abc.com is owned by a different team and serviceA will be owned by a different team. I want to make least number of changes in abc.com code. And I can update or change my serviceA as per my need without affecting abc.com code.

What library/package in react will help me achieve this ? I am new to react.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with [react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). In react router, each route is represented by a `Route` component.

So in your main app you could do this:

```
// app.js

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { PackageARoutes } from "package-a";
import { PackageBRoutes } from "package-b";

function App() {
  return (
     <Router>
       <PackageARoutes />
       <PackageBRoutes />
     </Router>
  );
}
```

And in each package:

```
// package-a/index.js

import { Route } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { Page1 } from "./pages/page1";

export function PackageARoutes() {
  return (
   <>
     <Route path="/serviceA/page1" component={Page1} />
   </>
  );
}
```

```
// package-b/index.js

import { Route } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { Page1 } from "./pages/page1";

export function PackageBRoutes() {
  return (
   <>
     <Route path="/serviceB/page1" component={Page1} />
   </>
  );
}
```